# URL Rewrite rule based on certain conditions

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am in process to apply URL rewriting rule based on certain condition in my .htaccess file but have got struck due to my near to zero level knowledge of URL rewriting using Apache .htacces.Here is my use case

i have few plugins in my WordPress application and those plugins making use to certain CSS and JavaScript,all i want that those URLs should be served from the CDN server, due to some issues i can not use a simple rewrite which will rewrite the URL for entire application as that thing is breaking my application functionality.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/pluginA/abc.css
http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/pluginA/abc.js
```

i want that when the CSS and JS are from this plugin (Plugin A ) or any other plugin whose URL i want to rewrite, The URL should get rewritten as

```
http://www.cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/pluginA/abc.css
http://www.cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/pluginA/abc.js
```

i am not sure how to do such conditional based URL rewriting,Any suggestion will really be 
helpful

**Edit**
This is my current .htaccess file in the root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i have created a new `.htaccess` file under `wp-content` folder as per `Michael` suggestion with following entry

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase  /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.+\.(css|js)$
RewriteRule wp-content/plugins/(nivo-slider-light|Usernoise|lightbox-plus|wp-content-slideshow|content-slide)/(.+)$ http:/cdn.cloudfront.net/wp-content/plugins/$1/$2 [L,R=302,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

but seems this is not working as still for the above plugins all the css and js file are being served with the URL from localhost and not from my CDN server.I even commented out these lines from my root's .htaccess file

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
```

but this also did not made any changes in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be placed in .htaccess inside the root directory. Any plugins you want rewritten can be placed inside the `()` separated by `|`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite pluginA plugin X, and pluginZ to the CDN. Add add more with |
RewriteRule wp-content/plugins/(pluginA|pluginX|pluginZ)/(.+)$ http:/www.cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/$1/$2 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Note: the above rewrites all the plugin files.  If it should only be the css & js files, use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js)$
RewriteRule wp-content/plugins/(pluginA|pluginX|pluginZ)/(.+)$ http:/www.cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/$1/$2 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: i tried this on my local machine, seems its not working.Is there any relation with the URL like `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider-light/nivo-slider.css?ver=3.3.1` where this part `?ver=3.3.1` is coming with every URL being provided by the plugins.

Comment: @user702325 Add `QSA` in with `[L,R=301,QSA]` This appends the existing querystring onto the request.

Comment: i tried this one also but this is also not working.i have the following entry in my `.htaccess` file located at root `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})` not sure if this has any relation with that or not

Comment: @user702325 Do you only have those `RewriteCond` lines in your current .htaccess? Without a `RewriteRule` they won't actually do anything, and in fact they'll conflict with anything new you add since they're made to apply to the first `RewriteRule` they encounter. Comment them out and see if it works - they're not serving any purpose without a `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion but seems this is also not working for me.I have updated my question with additional information, please have a look.

Comment: @user702325 Ah, sorry - this should have gone in the site root directory, _not_ in the wp-content directory.  Just add it into your existing rewrite rules, probably best to add it above the two `REQUEST_FILENAME` lines.  It can probably just be added to the end though.

Comment: need to see closely as this suggestion is also not working i placed the lines at your mentioned positions as well played with some other combination but seems like this rule is not at all being read.