# URL Rewrite Rule using .htaccess not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

In continuation with my previous Question [url-rewrite-rule-based-on-certain-conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164476/url-rewrite-rule-based-on-certain-conditions)
I am trying to do a URL rewrite like this

```
http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/pluginA/abc.css
http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/pluginA/abc.js
```

i want that when the CSS and JS are from this plugin (Plugin A ) or any other plugin whose URL i want to rewrite, The URL should get rewritten as

```
http://www.cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/pluginA/abc.css
http://www.cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/pluginA/abc.js
```

This is what i tried as in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.+\.(css|js)$
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/(nivo-slider-light|Usernoise|lightbox-plus|wp-content-slideshow|content-slide)/(.+)$ http:/abc.cloudfront.net/wp-content/plugins/$1/$2 [L,R=302,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried every possible way to rewrite the URL so that JS and CSS should get served from my CDN server, but seems like the rule is never been picked up by apache.Any help/pointer in this regard will really be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe because of `RewriteBase /wordpress/` line ?

Comment: @LazyOne:This is one from my local machine and i have removed it while deploying on server but nothing was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this your first rule (right after `RewriteBase` line)

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/plugins/(nivo-slider-light|Usernoise|lightbox-plus|wp-content-slideshow|content-slide)/[^.]+\.(css|js))$ http://abc.cloudfront.net/$1 [L,R,NC]
```

Also if it doesn't work try moving your `*.js` and `*.css` files away from local directories under `wp-content/plugins/` path.

Comment: no that did not worked out.I am not sure about your second suggestion for moving `js` and `css` file

Comment: Can you check your access.log to make sure what URI you're getting in Apache.

Comment: i checked the URL and its the same original one not the rewritten one `[16/Apr/2012:19:20:38 +0530] "GET /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider-light/custom-nivo-slider.css?ver=3.3.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 772`

Comment: Alright in your code (and I copy pasted) you had `http:/abc.cloudfront.net` instead of `http://abc.cloudfront.net`. I just tested with this change and it is working fine now. Make sure your .htaccess above is in `/wordpress` folder under DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: i tried the above things and still it snot working for me as the URL are still not rewritten, but i can see a strange issue as seen from firebug.CSS and JS for which we have rewritten the URL, according to firebug are not available as they are being referred as `www.mysitedomian.com/wordpress/...path` and since WordPress is not there so i can understand the problem, but we have configured the URL as `http:/abc.cloudfront.net` and not `www.mysitedomian.com`, so i am not sure why this is happening.I tried the code on server (live) but its not doing any URL rewrite

Comment: First note that `http:/abc.cloudfront.net` is invalid URL, it should be `http://abc.cloudfront.net` (note `//` instead of `/` after `http:`). Secondly you're saying `/wordpress` folder doesn't exist under DOCUMENT_ROOT. This is really strange. If this is true then why do you have `RewriteBase /wordpress/` in your .htaccess?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i correct the URL from `http:/` to `http://`,regarding second part, `wordpress` folder is only there in my local machine so i am using `RewriteBase /wordpress/` but since there is not wordpress folder on the server so for server i am using `RewriteBase /` in my `.htaccess` file for server

Comment: In that case I edited my answer one more time. Pls check it now.

Comment: seems like nothing is working here :(.tried this one also and Apache is not picking the rule at all.`access.log` still showing `GET /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider-light/nivo-slider.css?ver=3.3.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -`

Comment: In your log snippet you can see HTTP status code = `200` which means `/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider-light/custom-nivo-slider.css?ver=3.3.1` was indeed found locally however you also wrote `/wordpress` doesn't exist locally. You see these 2 points are contradicting each other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10129/discussion-between-user702325-and-anubhava)

Comment: i added the `RewriteLog` but its not adding any log to the rewrite.log file and when i tried to add the following line `RewriteLogLevel 7` i am unable to see page ad it was showing connection was reset or page took a lot of time to load

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help investigation :) We need more debug info to track it. Do you also have a .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT? If yes can you try renaming to something for testing?